# How to use the correct PHP version? phpinfo says another version

Tags: php, fedora, httpd

Fedora 17. I have a PHP version installed on my system, let name it as **phpMain**.

And I've compiled another PHP version from source using this option:

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/php/5.x.y

I will call it as **phpAlt**.

Then I went to the **/usr/bin** folder and rename the **php** to **phpMain** and created a symlink on **/usr/bin/** pointing to **/opt/php/5.x.y/bin/php**.

When I type in the terminal:

> php -v

I got the **phpAlt** version, and its ok.
But running a **phpinfo** project in the brownser I get the **wrong** version, the **phpMain** version.

What I need to change for the **phpinfo** shows the correct **phpAlt** version?

Comment: You have to restart the webserver for it to pick up the changes.  I'm not sure if you did that, but it isn't listed in your steps.

Comment: I tried `sudo service httpd stop && sudo service httpd start` too.

Answer (score 1):

**For the command line:**
Adjust your search path (`$PATH` environment variable) so the directory containing **phpAlt** is before the one containing **phpMain**.

**For the webserver:** (assuming you use PHP as an Apache module)
Remove the `LoadModule` line for the system PHP, and add one pointing at the .so for **`phpAlt**.

Comment: I had installed php and httpd using yum normally. I had search on /etc/php.ini and /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and didn't seen no LoadModule php? Where is it? Or, how to put it?

Comment: @GarouDan On Fedora you'll find it at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`.

Comment: Lol, looks almost. But I tried `tree | grep "\.so"` on the compiled directory /opt/php/php-5.x.y and no results (`tree | grep "\.php"` return results).

Comment: Should I pass the entire paht (`/opt/php/php-5.x.y/bin/php`) instead `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` and `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so`? How should I put at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`?

Comment: @GarouDan [Please refer to the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) -- If built in accordance with their instructions following the steps they outline will work. (If not, rebuild in accordance with the manual.)

Comment: I'm trying to follow the manual but the line `--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs` or `--with-apxs2=/opt/apache2/apxs ` is not working. Whats the correct path to pass? (I had installed apache using yum install httpd).

Comment: I had found /usr/sbin/apxs, maybe this can help somebody too.

Comment: But now the problem is `--with-mysql=/usr/`. I trying to compile on a 64-bit machine and I have mysql and mysql-devel installed (by yum).